# Get first character of a string SHELL

Tags: linux, sh

I want to first the first character of a string, for example:

```
$>./first $foreignKey
```

And I want to get `"$"`

I googled it and I found some solutions but it concerns only bash and not `Sh !`

Comment: If you type `./first $foreigKey` into any bourne compatible shell, the process that is spawned will never see the `$`.   What you seem to be asking for is impossible.

Answer (score 22):

This should work on any Posix compatible shell (including `sh`). `printf` is not required to be a builtin but it often is, so this may save a fork or two:

```
first_letter=$(printf %.1s "$1")
```

**Note:** (*Possibly I should have explained this six years ago when I wrote this brief answer.*) It might be tempting to write `%c` instead of `%.1s`; that produces exactly the same result except in the case where the argument `"$1"` is empty. `printf %c ""` actually produces a NUL byte, which is not a valid character in a Posix shell; different shells might treat this case differently. Some will allow NULs as an extension; others, like bash, ignore the NUL but generate an error message to tell you it has happened. The precise semantics of `%.1s` is "*at most* 1 character at the start of the argument, which means that `first_letter` is guaranteed to be set to the empty string if the argument is the empty string, without raising any error indication.

Comment: This. The guy just asked how to get first char of string, not any interpreter things as the comments of paxdiablo's answer kept saying...

Comment: Why use `printf '%.1s' ` instead of `printf '%c'`?

Comment: @fravadona: To avoid an error message if `$1` happens to be an empty string.

Answer (score 18):

Well, you'll probably need to escape that *particular* value to prevent it being interpreted as a shell variable but, if you don't have access to the nifty `bash` substring facility, you can still use something like:

```
name=paxdiablo
firstchar=`echo $name | cut -c1-1`
```

If you *do* have `bash` (it's available on most Linux distros and, even if your login shell is not `bash`, you should be able to run scripts with it), it's the much easier:

```
firstchar=${name:0:1}
```

For escaping the value so that it's not interpreted by the shell, you need to use:

```
./first \$foreignKey
```

and the following `first` script shows how to get it:

```
letter=`echo $1 | cut -c1-1`
echo ".$letter."
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use _bash_. And your first solution doesn't work for character "$"
`echo ${1} | cut -c-1`
I get an empty output

Comment: @03t02: yes it does, you just have to escape it, as I stated. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a school project ! And they will try to crash my program, it should work without escape the `"$"` character in the first parameter :/

Comment: @03t02: it can't be done. The `$` is interpreted by the shell before your program/script is even started. If you don't want to interpret it, you have to escape it somehow.

Comment: you can simply just use `cut -c 1` instead of `cut -c1-1` if you just want one character (the first one in this case). - i witnessed noobs being confused by this.

Comment: I prefer rici answer, because IMHO `printf` is also portable (`dash`, `busybox sh`), but faster than invoke `cut`.

Answer (score 10):

for shell sh

```
echo "hello" | cut -b 1 # -b 1 extract the 1st byte
h

echo "hello" |grep -o "." | head -n 1
h

echo "hello" | awk -F "" '{print $1}'
h
```

you can try this for bash:

```
s='hello'; echo ${s:0:1}
h
```

Comment: No I can't because this is a _bash_ solution

Comment: @03t02 Updated my ans please have a look

Comment: i would rather suggest `cut -c 1` instead of `cut -b 1` but in most cases this would be more or less a nitpick.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it is an old question.
recently I got the same problem, according to POSIX shell manual about substring processing, this is my solution without involving any subshell/fork

`a="some string here"
printf 'first char is "%s"\n' "${a%"${a#?}"}"`

Comment: Remove the smallest suffix which is all but the first character as removal of the smallest prefix of one character.

This can be found in XCU - Shell Command Langauge, for example in the The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02 - x-ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/389209/9340

Comment: This is the only true POSIX shell solution that will for sure never spawn an external process. If `printf` is a built-in, though, it also won't spawn an external shell and will probably be faster, as this solution creates a temporary string (`${a#?}`) and has to perform string globbing twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf -v first_character "%c" "${variable}"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This answer is concise, correct and readable. Good code speaks for itself.

Comment: However, `printf -v` is a bash extension and OP was pretty clear that bash-only solutions wouldn't work for them.